# Viewer functionality in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, viewer

Is there a viewer function/display in QGIS as it is in ArcGIS. Or is there an other possibility to limit the access (just visualisation, no analysis)?

Comment: Please add more detail? Why?    As far as I know, the only reason to use the viewer from ESRI is to avoid paying the software license.    QGIS can by customised to have less menu items / tools available.

Comment: It's actually a question my boss asked me. So far I didn't find anything alike in qgis. He would like to have a viewer because some people just need to have a look at the data but they don't need to do analysis. I think, he wants something like a restricted access for some people.

Comment: Did you know that you can use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with responses to queries raised as Comments?

Comment: Out of the box, there is no functionality like this. But with a custom build, it's possible to make a standalone viewer.

Comment: Ok. As I'm very new to the subject, can you explain a little more about how I can have such a viewer? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the end users to be able to access the data flexibly, say, by web browser? That way all you have to do is give them a link, rather than installing software on their machine? This would be the best way to distribute information to viewers.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I think the idea is rather that you can open the software and just have a look at a created map, but you can't change anything.

Comment: Why not serve the data you want people to visualize as a WMS, then they can use any GIS client that supports WMS.